# Cannot convert value of type `AuthResultCallback`?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui, handler

I know about other similar questions, but they are to do with `Auth.auth().signIn` and `signUp` respectively, where there is a completion handler argument present within the function.

I'm trying to include a sign in the anonymous function to my `SessionStore` class so that my app observes the state of the user, i.e., whether he is signed in (anonymously or otherwise) or signed out, and accordingly display the relevant view.

However, when trying to add anonymous sign up to my `SessionStore` class, I get the following error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'AuthResultCallback' (aka '(Optional<User>, Optional<Error>) -> ()') to expected argument type 'AuthDataResultCallback?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional<AuthDataResult>, Optional<Error>) -> ()>')`

My code is as follows:

```swift
class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<SessionStore, Never>()

    @Published var session: User? {didSet {self.didChange.send(self)}}
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

     func listen() {
         handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                self.session = User(uid: user.uid, email: user.email)
            } else {
                self.session = nil
            }
        })
    }

    func signUp(email: String, password: String, handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
    }

    func signIn(email: String, password: String, handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
    }

    func signOut() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.session = nil
        } catch {
            print("Error signing user out")
        }
    }

    func signUpAnonymously(handler: @escaping AuthResultCallback) {

        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously(completion: handler) // **ERROR APPEARS HERE**

    }

    func unbind() {
        if let handle = handle {
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        unbind()
    }

}

struct User {

    var uid: String
    var email: String?

    init(uid: String, email: String?) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.email = email
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: both completion handlers are different

Comment: `typealias AuthDataResultCallback = (FIRAuthDataResult?, Error?) -> Void`

Comment: What's the declaration of `signInAnonymously(completion:)`? It seems to want a `AuthDataResultCallback` parameter, while you gave it a `AuthResultCallback` one. That's normal then, there is a mismatch.

Comment: `typealias AuthResultCallback = (FIRUser?, Error?) -> Void`

Comment: Note that the function `func signUpAnonymously(handler:` isn't being called from anywhere else in the code so we don't know how it's being used or what's being passed in. And, and @Larme mentioned, this `@escaping AuthResultCallback` is a mismatch as [.signInAnonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#signinanonymouslycompletion:) is expecting `AuthDataResultCallback`

Comment: @Jay you're right, it was a very stupid error on my part. Is there a way to mark a comment as "correct" like there is for answers?
(I'll delete this comment later to clean the thread up)

Comment: There isn't but it was really more of a typo type error than anything else. Glad we were able to help! Upvote @Larme comment.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you pasted is from an outdated tutorial. As of Xcode 11 beta 5, you no longer need to use `PassthroughSubject` to send notifications about property changes. [Sarun's blog post](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-changes-in-xcode-11-beta-5/#objectbinding%2Fbindableobject-are-deprecated) has a great and concise section on what has changed, I encourage you to read it.

Please also note that you don't need to define your own `User` class if you only care about the user's ID and their email address, as these attributes are already defined on Firebase's own `User` type (by way of implementing the [`UserInfo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Protocols/UserInfo.html) protocol).

Here is a snippet that shows how to implement the callback you're interested in (see `registerStateListener`).

```swift
class AuthenticationService: ObservableObject {

  @Published var user: User?

  private var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

  init() {
    registerStateListener()
  }

  func signIn() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
      Auth.auth().signInAnonymously()
    }
  }

  func signOut() {
    do {
      try Auth.auth().signOut()
    }
    catch {
      print("Error when trying to sign out: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }

  func updateDisplayName(displayName: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
      let changeRequest = user.createProfileChangeRequest()
      changeRequest.displayName = displayName
      changeRequest.commitChanges { error in
        if let error = error {
          completionHandler(.failure(error))
        }
        else {
          if let updatedUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            print("Successfully updated display name for user [\(user.uid)] to [\(updatedUser.displayName ?? "(empty)")]")
            // force update the local user to trigger the publisher
            self.user = updatedUser
            completionHandler(.success(updatedUser))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private func registerStateListener() {
    if let handle = handle {
      Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
    }
    self.handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
      print("Sign in state has changed.")
      self.user = user

      if let user = user {
        let anonymous = user.isAnonymous ? "anonymously " : ""
        print("User signed in \(anonymous)with user ID \(user.uid). Email: \(user.email ?? "(empty)"), display name: [\(user.displayName ?? "(empty)")]")
      }
      else {
        print("User signed out.")
        self.signIn()
      }
    }
  }

}
```

If you're interested in more background, check out my article series about building a to-do app with SwiftUI and Firebase: [part 1](https://peterfriese.dev/replicating-reminder-swiftui-firebase-part1/) (building the UI using SwiftUI), [part 2](https://peterfriese.dev/replicating-reminder-swiftui-firebase-part2/) (storing data in Firestore and using Firebase Anonymous Auth), [part 3](https://peterfriese.dev/replicating-reminder-swiftui-firebase-part3/) (Sign in with Apple)